# Exceptions of different scope combinations in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am studying about the scope in Google Analytics and, obviously, I have read that we shouldn't combine different scope metrics and dimensions. However, I have some questions regarding the exceptions allowed. I will give some examples:

A. **Users by Page** (user-level metric by hit-level dimension)

I would expect to get a table that shows how many users visited each page of my site. Based on my research, this combination can be used because hits do contain user information (the client id).

B. **New Users by Source / Medium** (user-level metric by session-level dimension)

Why are we allowed to combine New Users with Source / Medium, while we are not allowed to combine Users with Source / Medium (or at least we must be careful)?

C. **Sessions by User Type** (session-level metric by user-level dimension)

Why are we allowed to combine Sessions and User Type?

D. **Pageviews by User Type** (hit-level metric by user-level dimension)

Why are we allowed to combine Pageviews and User Type?

E. **Pageviews by Source / Medium** (hit-level metric by session-level dimension)

Are, and if yes why, are we allowed to use this combination if we want to calculate the number of pageviews generated from users arriving from a specific source/medium?

F. **Bounce Rate by Page** (session-level metric by hit-level dimension)

Regarding this combination, I have read that we should never combine session-level metrics and hit-level dimensions, because when combining any session-level metric with a hit-level dimension, the metric will only contain data from the first hit of the session. However, in this case we do have such a combination. Why?

Also, I have found these two articles:

1. In the first one, bounce rate is noted as session-level metric. https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2016/11/30/understanding-scope-google-analytics-reporting/
2. In the second one, bounce rate is noted as hit-level metric.
   What is the correct one?

G. **Exit Rate by Page** (session-level metric by hit-level dimension)

The same holds for this combination.

Comment: Show some screenshots, pls. In my opinion you asked too many questions for one post.

Comment: My questions are not about the results and the figures per se. They are about understanding the reason we can use these combinations despite the fact that they are of different scope. So, there is no point of screenshots.

Comment: In general, it is not forbidden to cross different areas and in some cases it is not even wrong as long as you know how to read the result that is given. Then there are dimensions and metrics that cannot be crossed, probably because they would require an expensive calculation and a senseless result or because they are collected and processed in a way for which it is not possible to cross them by Google. With the screenshots I was referring to showing the differences, to prevent those who want to answer you point by point from doing it for you considering that you asked 8 questions in 1.